# Reading FIle Using Threads

Tags: c, multithreading, file-read

How we can read a whole file using multiple threads if the total number of lines are not given ?

Maybe first we calculate total numbers of lines but I don't think its a good approach.

Can Someone Help ?

Comment: How would you calculate the total number of lines without reading the entire file?

Comment: For Example I m using 4 threads and i want to find a string from a file I want that Each thread run parallel any of the thread find the string the program will stop Basically I want to achieve this..

Comment: You need to clarify what "read a whole file" means. Line by line ? As text?, as fixed length records? As parsed JSON or XML ? Further, just fyi, If the file is contiguous, multi-threaded reading is pointless unless it's on solid-state hardware (and even there, it's questionable). On spindles the seek flapping alone will *reduce*, not increase, performance; you're better off in that scenario simply sequentially scanning the file, or mapping it directly into process space.

Comment: The only thing that would make sense, if there is substantial processing you need to do for your lines, is to read the file sequentially and push lines into a queue which will be consumed by multiple threads (ideally a pool of threads with the count equal to the number of cores in your system). I.e. single producer-multiple consumer scenario. Actually creating 4 different pointers and going over the file doesn't seem like something that would help with performance.